# Excel: Using either Red, Green, Blue numbers or RGB Code to fill a cell

Tags: excel

It's been awhile since I did something like this so I am struggling and could use the help. I currently have a spreadsheet where I have listed the Red, Green, and Blue values of a colour, currently I can Fill a cell with that colour if I open the menu and do custom colour. I'm wondering if there is a way that this can be done automatically?

Here is an example of what I am wanting with some blank colour cells so you can see what I am referring too:

[image: Screenshot of Spreadsheet]

Any help would be appreciated

Thank you!

Comment: Doable with VBA.

Comment: @BigBen I can't figure out the VBA on this one; suggestions?

Comment: Start with the [`RGB`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/rgb-function) function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the [`RGB`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/rgb-function) function:

```
Sub ApplyColour()
    With ActiveSheet
        Dim lastRow As Long
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row
        
        Dim rw As Range
        For Each rw In .Range("H5:K" & lastRow).Rows
            With rw
                .Cells(4).Interior.Color = _
                    RGB(.Cells(1).Value, .Cells(2).Value, .Cells(3).Value)
            End With
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: .cells(4) - I was thinking one has to write .cells(row,column)! How come .cells(4) is the 4th column?, Should it not be the 4th row? please explain

Comment: @Prema - one can refer to the `.Cells` by index here, and the order is across columns and then down rows. Since each `rw` has 4 cells, the 4th cell is the 4th column.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your knowledge.